# Clear a swap chain image on a specific rectangle to a specific color

Tags: graphics, 3d, vulkan

If I'm not missing something, there are two functions which allow me to explicitly clear a swap chain image: `vkCmdClearColorImage` and `vkCmdClearAttachments`.

However, I would like to clear on a specific rectangle and to a specific color. While `vkCmdClearColorImage` allows me to specify the color, I cannot specify the rectangle. And while `vkCmdClearAttachments` allows me to specify the rectangle, I cannot specify the color (I guess it's using the color color specified in the render pass).

So, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give `vkCmdClearAttachments` an array of `VkClearAttachment` structs containing the clear color, for the attachments.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdClearAttachments.html

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkClearAttachment.html

Comment: Is there a way to tell vkCmdClearAttachments to clear the whole rectangle if no rectangle is specified? According to the docs, rectCount must be greater than `0`.